# Why are User variables set with SetEnvironmentVariable not visible from powershell commands sent via cmd window?

Tags: powershell

When I run these two commands in a powershell window, I get "Test Value." printed out.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable', 'Test value.')
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable')
```

But then when I run these two commands in a cmd window, I don't get anything printed out.

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command  {[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable', 'Test value.')}
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command  [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable')
```

Why can I not access the variable I've set in the second example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing this behavior because each process maintains its own environment (after it's inherited the environment from its parent). The parent process (cmd.exe in this case) does not see the changes made by powershell.exe since those changes die with the powershell process.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is bad form to be mixing two shells like this. Either use
PowerShell or use cmd.exe. However if you insist on doing it this way:

```sh
C:\> powershell "[environment]::setEnvironmentVariable('foo', 'bar', 'm')"
C:\> powershell "[environment]::getEnvironmentVariable('foo')"
bar
```

Note you could also do

```sh
C:\> powershell "$env:foo"
bar
```

Or the sane option

```sh
C:\> echo %foo%
bar
```

Note that you might need to restart cmd.exe before the variable is recognized in
the environment.

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/966a392e9b395/windows.ps1#L86)

Comment: I think you should make it clearer that this is changing the machine default for the environment variables so it will affect all future processes on that machine.